# Way to send image to Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, file-upload, httprequest

I have a little situation, when im trying to send the uploaded image from front end to backend, the file object is empty. So i receive an error from backend that the file.path cant be found, when im trying to upload the image from postman, it works, I dont know what are the differences and why on postman works.

Im using react hook form, here is the payload:

[image]

The console.log of the image before sending it
[image]

Can someone please tell me what is happening here?

Comment: "e.target.files[0]" are you setting the file into the state like this?

Comment: check the Content-Type of request headers

Comment: im using a library with drag&drop in react, and gives me the image through props, but the console.log of image[0] looks fine, you can see it in last attached image

Comment: @zer0321 in frontend?

Comment: @MariusSeba yes, on the tab headers，you can compare it with postman

Comment: @zer0321 the headers are the same